# Adding a space character to my regex

Tags: regex

I would like some help in getting this regex to accept the space character.

The following regex works `^a|a$|a` but this one doesn't `^tips to|tips to$|tips to`.

Comment: have you tried using `\\ ` before the space? like this: `tips\ to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try escaping just the last space (the regex engine will then "see" that "tips to" is one block - at least for the last OR)

`^tips to|tips to$|tips\ to`

or to be on the safe side group what your searching for

`^(tips to)|(tips to)$|(tips to)`

**[EDIT 1]**

so here's the solution the OP is using:

```
^"tips to"|"tips to"$|"tips to"
```

Comment: Pastacool, you grouping suggestion was quite close to the solution. This works: ^"tips to"|"tips to"$|"tips to" . At the referenced website in my original question the author faq addressed that particular challenge. Here it is again.                                                                                                                                                            2.5 How do I include spaces in my search?

To include spaces in your search enclose your search in double quotes.
For example, here is how to search for foo<space>bar: "foo bar"

Comment: so, with the grouping, does it give you the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

Space is just as-is in a regex (you just put the space character, that should work). Alternatively you can use \s special character. For example, in Perl:

```
my $test = "Helloworld";
if ($test =~ m/ /)
{
    print("Has space\n");
}
```

Also if you can specify more what you want to use the regex for, we might be able to help better.

Comment: while it's true you use a space as-is, depending on your programming language you may need to escape that space somehow so that after it is parsed, the regex engine sees the space.

Comment: As you said, that's specific for some programming languages and he/she didn't specify any programming language. Good to know though.

Comment: As above, the pattern you are using (^tips to|tips to$|tips to) should work just fine, and certainly does in C#.  Can you provide information on the context that you are attempting to apply this regex pattern in?  Language, Regular Expression engine?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression that matches 1 space character is 1 space character.